# Dynamodb Update for multiple list items with multiple key values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We are updating data in an Excel sheet for a particular event id, We need to retrieve the primary key item from the dynamodb table for the particular event id and need to update values in the excel.

Doing this manually for few articles is ok. But if we need to update 10000 of event id values, how can we automate this process through python or any other method? Please Assist on this

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to automate this in Excel, then one option is to use the Office Interop APIs for Excel from your favorite .NET language (C# is really easy to use for this sort of task). Dynamo has client SDKs for .NET, again making it relatively easy to query your source table.

For the .Net SDK for Dynamo, start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-intro.html

For Office automation, you have two options:

1. You can either write a .Net application that would interface with Excel and process the file, reading from Dynamo
2. You can try using the automation features from Excel via scripting (but I am not sure how well that would work with the external dependency on the AWS SDK)

For the latter you might start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

There are lots of examples for automating Excel using C#. If you find that you're stuck on something in particular, feel free to ask here on SO but the more focused the question the quicker and better answers you'll get.

As far as the approach for your particular task, I would:

- make a console application that opens the Excel document (workbook) you want to edit
- enumerate the sheets and pick the one you need to update (presumably the first one?!)
- then, for each of the rows in the sheet, read the eventid from the corresponding cell
- make the DynamoDB query and get the data you need for that event
- update the cells for that row
- repeat this for all rows until you're done

As a potential optimization, if there aren't that many records in Dynamo (10,000 is a pretty low number), I would look into scanning the Dynamo table into memory first and then doing the lookups in the memory. This has the added benefit that it will be significantly cheaper. Scanning all 10K items and storing in memory will usually be on the order of 15-20 times cheaper than making individual Get requests for each item.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike !!! Will work on it .. Before doing this we need to take primary id for each event id to update .. Planning to do below approach 1.Search primary id for each event id 2.Store into memory 3.Then update the record correshponding eventid items

Answer (score 0):

followed below steps to complete the dynamodb update

1.We have read and converted source csv data into dictionary

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:   reader = csv.reader(f)   your_list
= list(reader) list_1=[] dict1={} for i in range(1, len(your_list)):
    dict1[your_list[0][0]]=your_list[i][0]
    dict1[your_list[0][1]]=your_list[i][1]
    dict1[your_list[0][2]]=your_list[i][2]
    dict1[your_list[0][3]]=your_list[i][3] list_1.append(dict1)
    dict1={}
```

I have not copied the complete script here , just pasted one small batch script

2.Using dynamodb scan operation compared the eventid in source and destination

We have faced data retrivel issue here , at a time we can get 1 MB of data in dynamodb

3.We have verified each batch records with dynamodb table and completed the update process